# Why does UIViewController extend under UINavigationBar, while UITableViewController doesn't?

Tags: ios, objective-c, layout, uiview, ios7

I have `UITabbarController` with `UINavigationController` in it. I have a subclass of `UIView` that I assign as the `view` of `UIViewController` in the `navController`. This is pretty standard stuff, right? This is how I do it

```
_productCategoryView = [[ProductCategoryView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
self.view = _productCategoryView;
```

This `view` has a `UITableView` as `subView`

```
_productCategoryTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
_productCategoryTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
_productCategoryTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self addSubview:_productCategoryTableView];
```

For the sake of debugging I am setting `self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]` on the view.

From the above initialization of `tableView` one might think that the view's and table's `frame` is same. However when I run in `iOS 7`, the view's origin is set behind the `UINavigationBar`. This is understandable because I am setting `self.navigationBar.translucent = YES;` in my subclass of `UINavigationController`. But what I don't understand is how come the table is sitting just below the `navBar`? Shouldn't it also start from `(0, 0)` which is behind the `navBar`? See screenshot `Scenario 1` below. Notice the blue hue behind `navBar`

[image: Scenario 1]

Now, I `push` another `viewController` on the navigation stack, simply by using `[self.navigationController pushViewController.....]`. Again I have a custom `UIView` with a `tableView` in it. However I also have a `UILabel` above this table, and again for debugging, I gave it a `redColor`. This time I am setting the label's `origin` to be almost same as the view's

```
CGRect boundsInset = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(self.bounds, UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10));

CGSize textSize = [_titleLabel.text sizeWithFont:_titleLabel.font
                               constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(boundsInset.size.width, MAXFLOAT)
                                   lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
printSize(textSize);
_titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(boundsInset.origin.x,
                               boundsInset.origin.y,
                               boundsInset.size.width,
                               textSize.height);
```

So, going by the logic above, the label should be visible, right? But this time it's not. This time the label is behind the `navBar`.

[image: Scenario - 2]

Notice, the red hue behind navBar.

I would really like to align the subView below the navBar consistently. My questions are

`1. How is the tableView offset by 64pixels (height of nav + status bar in iOS 7) automatically, even though it's frame is same as the view's?`

`2. Why does that not happen in the second view?`

Comment: Are you building with Xcode 5 and the iOS7 SDK?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

By default, UITableViewController's views are automatically inset in iOS7 so that they don't start below the navigation bar/status bar. This is controller by the "Adjust scroll view insets" setting on the Attributes Inspector tab of the UITableViewController in Interface Builder, or by the `setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:` method of UIViewController.

For a UIViewController's contents, if you don't want its view's contents to extend under the top/bottom bars, you can use the Extend Edges Under Top Bars/Under Bottom Bars settings in Interface Builder. This is accessible via the `edgesForExtendedLayout` property.

Comment: Thanks @Greg. setting `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;` did the trick.

Comment: Thanks.  Addressing edgesForExtendedLayout  completed resolved the uitableview-as-a-subview-of-navcontroller layout issue for me; had spent countless hours on this for the past 8 months.

Comment: When doing a push transition with navigationController, I noticed there is a 'delayed' color treatment applied to the navigation bar. What causes this and how to remove it ?

Comment: Using @unspokenblabber's snippet in the comment above, this also prevents you from having to set a manual 64px top margin for View Controller XIBs.

Comment: @IphoneDeveloper, try: `self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;`

Comment: This worked for me: `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];` The "Extend Under Top Bar" setting in Interface Builder seems to be only for preview, it has not effect on the behavior of the view at run time.

Comment: For me nothing is working, In my case , I have CollectionView controller which hides navigation bar, when any modal view appears on it, after dismissing modal view  self.topLayoutGuide.length is 20.000000 which make my view to overlap with status bar , It should be 0. How I can set this toplayoutguide length. Any help..

Comment: Tried `.all` and `[]` but no luck on iOS 13. I'm creating a navigation controller then adding the view controller setting with `navigationController.setViewControllers([vc], animated: false)`. Ideas?

Answer (score 121):

Objective-C:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
 }
```

Swift 2:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None
```

Swift 3+:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
```

Comment: Setting `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []` changes the `UINavigationBar` color.

Answer (score 10):

@Gank's answer is correct, but the best place to do this is on the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` (if you have one):

```
func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    viewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None
}
```

Comment: @Jaybo thanks, yes, where you put code has big implications.