# What is the extend edge property in UIViewController for ?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have read on the forums about this property, mostly its people setting this this property to false or unchecking it in the storyboard. 
I have done this myself because when I have a UINavigation Controller embedded in a View, the top bar pushes my UITextView down so the text starts editing at the bottom.

Unchecking Extended Edges Under Top Bars in the StoryBoard in the UIViewController solves my problem but I don't understand what is going on.

Can someone give an explanation on what the purpose of this property is, I would like to know more about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, UITableViewController's views are automatically inset in iOS7 so that they don't start below the navigation bar/status bar. This is controller by the "Adjust scroll view insets" setting on the Attributes Inspector tab of the UITableViewController in Interface Builder, or by the `setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:` method of UIViewController.

For a UIViewController's contents, if you don't want its view's contents to extend under the top/bottom bars, you can use the Extend Edges Under Top Bars/Under Bottom Bars settings in Interface Builder. This is accessible via the `edgesForExtendedLayout` property.

*Reference:* [Why does UIViewController extend under UINavigationBar, while UITableViewController doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143353/why-does-uiviewcontroller-extend-under-uinavigationbar-while-uitableviewcontrol/19143661#19143661)

Comment: Do you think that the reason for doing this is to make sure that UI elements are not under the Navigation bar ?

Answer (score 1):

The [`edgesForExtendedLayout`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621515-edgesforextendedlayout) property, together with the `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` property, determines whether or not view controllers' views underlap top and bottom bars (navigation bar, toolbar, etc.)

Comment: So this explains why a UITextView that isn't completely set under the navigation bar doesn't start editing on the top? it seems like the UITextView got pushed down because it assumed it was under the navigation bar.

Comment: Well, with something like a text view or a table view, this is a scroll view. So there is an extra complication. It can extend under the nav bar, but then it can compensate by using the content inset (and scroll indicator inset). So two more properties come into play. Plus, if this is the top-level view, there is a view controller that causes the content inset to be set _automatically_ to compensate.

Answer (score 1):

See the images below:

I set 44 height red topview and 44 height red footview of tableview.

UIRectEdgeTop: The top edge of the rectangle.
UIRectEdgeBottom: The bottom edge of the rectangle.

[image]

[image]