# UIScrollView moves elements from their set positions

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xcode-storyboard

I am creating and IOS app for all of the engineers in my organisation to view and complete their jobs. However, when using a UIScrollView it moves the content away from where I place it on my storyboard.

With a normal UIView (not scroll) the elements are placed where I put them however it can overflow if there are large number of switches to place on the page (dynamically) so I need to be able to scroll through items.

I am using the [storyboard here](https://pastebin.com/PD8UzqJ3). To create my main layout.
However, from my scroll layout I use this code to add buttons.

```cs
y = StartY
x = StartX

foreach (var component in DetailItem.Components)
{
    y += yPls;
    UISwitch sw = new UISwitch(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(x, y, 51, 31));
    sw.OnTintColor = UIColor.Yellow;
    sw.ThumbTintColor = UIColor.Blue;

    sw.ValueChanged += (sender, e) => {
        var comp = sender as UISwitch;
        DetailItem.Components[component.Key] = comp.On;
    };

    UILabel lbl = new UILabel(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(x + 55, y, 200, 31));
    lbl.Text = component.Key;
    this.Add(sw);
    this.Add(lbl);
}
```

The problem is that elements are being moved from where I placed them, as shown here: 
[image: Storyboard Image]

Where I currently have the "Job Name:" Label selected but as you can see it is being moved.

Any help with this or ideas on why it happens would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the `ViewController` in storyboard and then in the `Properties` -> `Widget` -> `Extend Edges`, there is an option called **Under Top Bars**, uncheck that and your element in the scrollView will stay at the proper position.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

In the code behind, it should be:

```
this.EdgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None or UIRectEdge.None.all or UIRectEdge.Bottom;
```

`edgesForExtendedLayout` tells what edges should be extended (left, right, top, bottom, all, none or any combination of those). Extending bottom edge equals "Under Bottom Bars" tick, extending top edge equals "Under Top Bars" tick.

Check the [document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621515-edgesforextendedlayout?language=objc) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894642/what-is-the-extend-edge-property-in-uiviewcontroller-for) for more information.