# Add a UIImageView to the back of NavigationBar (NOT background image)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am trying to add a `UIImageView` to the back of a navigation bar. 
The reason is because I want to create a `UITableView` whose navigation bar is actually a picture (with back button on the left) but I want the picture to scroll with the tableview and when the picture is fully scrolled out. The navigation bar is shown as per normal. 
**My solution to this problem:** 
Add a `UIImageView` to the top of the `UITableView` and make the navigation bar transparent. Set a `contentOffset` for the `UITableView` which is a subclass of `UIScrollView` so that when the view is presented, it looks like the picture is filling the navigation status bar. 
[image: When the view is shown, it is exactly what I want.]
**Problem:** 
If I scroll up, instead of bouncing back, the transparent status bar is shown (with a color of the background as it is transparent). 
[image: If I scroll up, instead of bouncing back, I see the transparent navigation bar.]
**Possible way to solve this new problem:** 
I was thinking of trying to limit the `ScrollView` size to get around with problem but failed. 
So I feel is it possible to add the `UIImageView` to the "back" of the navigation bar so that it is there without any offset? Since that way, my life will be much easier. 
Any suggestions on solving this or another new approach to get the same UI/effect? 
Related [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143353/why-does-uiviewcontroller-extend-under-uinavigationbar-while-uitableviewcontrol)

Comment: You can add the image view as a subview of the navigation's titleview

Comment: @JadFeitrouni But that way, if I scroll further down, the image will always be there right? I want the image to be replaced by a normal title when it is scrolled off the screen.

Comment: Yes you're right, now I get what you're trying to do.

Comment: Did you try making the navigation bar transparent? Also, you can try hiding the navigation bar and use a custom and transparent bar instead.

Comment: @Ad-J Yes, I made the bar transparent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this by adding either a table header or cell at the top of the table which contains your image.

Create the table view so that it extends all the way to the top of the screen. Extend Under Top Bars option. I have not done this with a `UITableViewController` but I have done this with a `UITableView` embedded inside a `UIViewController`'s view with the top constraint set to 0 for the view rather than the top layout guide.

Now when you run this your table will fill the whole screen and the top header or cell will be at the top showing your picture.

When you scroll you can either use the `UIScrollViewDelegate` to detect the movement or implement `tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`

I'm not 100% sure when you want the navigation bar to go non clear. If its when the image goes off screen then didEndDisplayingCell should be good. If its when the cell bottom passed under the bottom of the navigation bar then scroll view might be your only option.

This will also bounce as you expect when you pull down and it should snap back to the top.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. I did the trick with `UITableViewController` by just checking off Adjust Scroll View Insets int the view controller inspector. Works like magic now!